# Retrofit making empty body for request in Android

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit in android and GsonConverterFactory is converter.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://xxxxxxx.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

I want send POST request with body.

```
public class MasterRequest 
{
}


public class User extends MasterRequest
{
 @SerializedName("email")
 public String email = null;
}

 @POST("{path}")
Call<MasterResponse> registerUser(@Path("path") String path, @Body MasterRequest masterRequest);
```

path is the URL that append with base URL.

When ever I send child class("User") object in parent class reference(MasterRequest), then converter shown empty json; "{}".

But when I send User class object to below registerUser Method, then it working fine.

```
@POST("{path}")
Call<MasterResponse> registerUser(@Path("path") String path, @Body User user);
```

How can I send child class object in parent class instance to make request body?

Answer (score 2):

That's how Gson works. The easiest way to serialize polymorphic objects is use [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java). You can find detailed tutorial [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson). Works great with Retrofit!